# Eventhandler on the last item in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, event-handling

I couldn't find any (for a beginner) readable information on this. Is it possible to have an event on the last item in a for loop:

```
array = ["foo", "bar", "john", "test"]
for item in array:
    print item
LastItemEvent: forLoop + lastItem
def lastItem:
    # call another function
    doneWithLoop()
```

Or do I need to have an incrementing integer count etc? Horrible example, but I hope you guys understand.

Comment: Are you saying you want to call the event on the last item before the loop does it's work on the last item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use else statement i guess:

```
for x in range(10):
    print x
else:
    print x**2
```

From Python docs:

> When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the sequence
>   is empty), the suite in the else clause, if present, is executed, and
>   the loop terminates.

Comment: The advantage of this is that you can know if the `for` loop ran successfully (no breaks). but this is very similar to adding another line following the loop which sounds too simple to warrant this question, however I could be wrong

Comment: @jamylak actually i am not able to find a reason why to use 'else' - i put the answer here in order to give and option for OP.

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror Do you know that python programs are sequential? One statement is executed after the other... If you want something to happen after something else finishes just write the code after that

Answer (score 1):

`item` *will* be the last element by the end of the loop as it takes on every value in the array(list really) so once it is done it will be set to the last one.

```
array = ["foo", "bar", "john", "test"]
for item in array:
    print item

print "last item", item
```

Comment: Hmm,my bad. Printing is a bad example. I want to do a whole other action, not involving item's value.

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror You don't want it's value? What do you want?

Comment: I'm using the loop to keep calling a function, but on it's last loop it need it to do some other stuff. I wish I could clarify it more.

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror Have you tried this? If so why doesn't it work?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my example hoping it will make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing something strange and there would be a better solution, if you explain what you really want to do. But if you really want to do what you are asking for, you can just iterate over all elements but the last one:

```
for item in array[:-1]:
    do_something(item)
```

And after that, you can of course do somethind else with the last element:

```
do_something_else(array[-1])
```

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways to achieve my goal on more clavor ways, but I'm not there yet. Thanks for the responses.